# Remove the strange one-pixel space around QPushButton with PySide/PyQT on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

This is my current code.

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QProgressBar,
    QPushButton,
    QTableWidget,
    QWidget
)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(6, 6, 6, 6)
        layout.addWidget(QTableWidget(), 0, 0, 1, 3)
        bar = QProgressBar()
        bar.setValue(50)
        bar.setTextVisible(False)
        layout.addWidget(bar, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        btn = QPushButton("OK")
        layout.addWidget(btn, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

And as you can see there is a strange one-pixel space around the button.

[image]

Is there a way to delete it?

I tried using CSS and putting negative margins without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That completely depends on the *QStyle*, apparently on Windows push buttons have a slightly bigger margin than other widgets.

This cannot be solved by using stylesheets, unless you provide the *full* stylesheet with borders for *all* button states (normal, pressed, disabled, etc).

There are only two solutions: bypass the painting on the widget, or use a proxystyle.

### `paintEvent()` override

```
class BiggerButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.style().proxy().objectName() != 'windowsvista':
            super().paintEvent(event)
            return
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        opt.rect.adjust(-1, -1, 1, 1)
        qp = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        qp.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_PushButton, opt)

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        btn = BiggerButton("OK")
```

### QProxyStyle

```
class Proxy(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(self, ctl, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if ctl == self.CE_PushButton:
            opt.rect.adjust(-1, -1, 1, 1)
        super().drawControl(ctl, opt, qp, widget)

# ...
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
if app.style().objectName() == 'windowsvista':
    app.setStyle(Proxy())
```

Comment: I have `AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QCommonStyle' object has no attribute 'baseStyle'` with the first approach.

Comment: The second approach is working with `if app.style().objectName() == 'windowsvista':`.

Comment: @0lan sorry. Change that line to `self.proxy().baseStyle().objectName()`.

Comment: For the first approach, only `self.style().proxy().objectName() != 'windowsvista':` is working. I tried on Linux too.

Comment: @0lan sorry again, I have mistaken the approach and thought that the line was for the Proxy class. I'll edit the post accordingly.